# How to update data in database using import excel laravel if any data exist

Tags: laravel, import, maatwebsite-excel

how to update data in database with import excel if data exist just update, and if not exist just save. i am using laravel 5.8 and maatwebsite 2.1

this is my controller :

```
$request->validate([
        'file' => 'required|mimes:csv,xls,xlsx',
        'divisi' => 'required',
        'file_type' => 'required'
    ]);
    $path = $request->file('file')->getRealPath();
    $data = Excel::load($path)->first();
    $divisi = $request->input('divisi');
    $file_type = $request->input('file_type');

    if(!empty($data) && $data->count()){
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {

            $arr[] = [
                'product_id' => $value->product_id, 
                'upc' => $value->upc, 
                'desc_a' => $value->desc_a, 
                'name' => $value->name, 
                'category' => $value->category, 
                'desc_b' => $value->desc_b, 
                'desc_c' => $value->desc_c, 
                'desc_d' => $value->desc_d, 
                'desc_e' => $value->desc_e, 
                'desc_f' => $value->desc_f, 
                'desc_g' => $value->desc_g, 
                'desc_h' => $value->desc_h, 
                'fixel_id' => $value->fixel_id, 
                'x' => $value->x, 
                'cost' => $value->cost, 
                'price' => $value->price, 
                'reg_movement' => $value->reg_movement, 
                'total_facings' => $value->total_facings, 
                'total_units' => $value->total_units, 
                'days_of_supply' => $value->days_of_supply, 
                'desc_i' => $value->desc_i, 
                'kode_lokasi' => $value->kode_lokasi, 
                'created_by' => Auth::user()->id,
                'updated_by' => Auth::user()->id,
                'created_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                'updated_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                'divisi' => $divisi, 
                'file_type' => $file_type];

        }
        if(!empty($arr)){
           
            Planogram::updateOrCreate($arr);
           
           } }
```

from this code my data always multiply with same record.
thank you

Comment: You should add only selected fields as first parameter ($selectedarr) in Planogram::updateOrCreate($selectedarr,$arr) which identify record as unique. Currently your using $arr which as first parameter and in that updateOrCreate function consider all fields to identify unique. So whenever the same record  comes that should update but currently it's consider new. Also, created_at and update_at always gives current timestamp. So this is the reason for considering updateOrCreate function as new record (as per above code).

Comment: @ankitb it work,but  now if my data 10 row, save data to db is only the last row

Answer (score 0):

Done, just change to this

```
if($data->count()){
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {     
            $getsku = PlanogramTemp::updateOrCreate([                  
                'desc_b' => $value->desc_b, 
                'desc_e' => $value->desc_e 
               ],[
                'product_id' => $value->product_id, 
                'upc' => $value->upc, 
                'desc_a' => $value->desc_a, 
                'name' => $value->name, 
                'category' => $value->category, 
                'desc_b' => $value->desc_b, 
                'desc_c' => $value->desc_c, 
                'desc_d' => $value->desc_d, 
                'desc_e' => $value->desc_e, 
                'desc_f' => $value->desc_f, 
                'desc_g' => $value->desc_g, 
                'desc_h' => $value->desc_h, 
                'fixel_id' => $value->fixel_id, 
                'x' => $value->x, 
                'cost' => $value->cost, 
                'price' => $value->price, 
                'reg_movement' => $value->reg_movement, 
                'total_facings' => $value->total_facings, 
                'total_units' => $value->total_units, 
                'days_of_supply' => $value->days_of_supply, 
                'desc_i' => $value->desc_i, 
                'kode_lokasi' => $value->kode_lokasi, 
                'created_by' => Auth::user()->id,
                'updated_by' => Auth::user()->id,
                'divisi' => $divisi, 
                'file_type' => $file_type]);

        }
```